# Removing the "offset" of rotation between two THREE.js objects

Tags: math, three.js, rotation, quaternions

I have two separate sensors that are broadcasting (every 50ms) their rotation in the form of a quaternion to my three.js webapp. The sensors are attached together so they are rotating together however their internal (relative) coordinates are different so my two three.js object don't "sync up".

What I want to do is to store the difference of their rotation on a button press and use that to "correct" one of the object's rotation continuously after that.

What I tried to do:

- Calculate the difference on a button press:

  ```
  let q1 = object1.getWorldQuaternion();
  let q2 = object2.getWorldQuaternion();
  qDiff = q1.multiply(q2.inverse());
  ```
- Add that difference to object1 when I update its rotation:

  ```
  q = recieveQuaternionFromSensor();
  object1.setRotationFromQuaternion(q.multiply(qDiff));
  ```

The above method doesn't work and I'm not sure what should I do differently.

Comment: It sounds like you're roughly on the right track. Have you tried different orders of operation like qdiff.mult (q) , instead?

Comment: I tried that as well but doesn't work either.

Comment: `recieveQuaternionFromSensor` gives world quaternion? Are the `Object1` and `Object2` children of the scene? Are they children of different parent?

Comment: Try creating a unit test for your code to make sure your logic does work as you thought, especially for such math-related problem.